# Can I deduct partnership loss from my income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-loss, partnership

I lost tens of thousands as passive loss when I withdrew from a partnership. However I'm not sure whether the capital loss is deductible. Since I have no passive income I think I could deduct $3,000 against my ordinary income and carry over the rest. FreeTaxUSA does not allow the deduction. What's going on?

Comment: What exactly was lost?  Your paid in capital?  An unrecoverable loan?

Comment: @quid I used money to invest in a partnership. Several years later I withdrew from it and got capital loss.